# Difference between Reflection and metadata

Tags: java, reflection, metadata

Does anyone can explain me:
What is the difference between `Reflection` and `metadata` in Java?
Last time I heard many people asking it more and more...

Comment: In what context people are asking. Database or class.

Comment: They are different things. What is the difference between streams and variables?

Comment: @Braj, In context of class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reflection is how you do inspect classes,methods etc and method at Runtime without knowing their existence at compile time.It is unlike statically typed code where the code is compiled for a known set of classes whereas Reflection can be used to load any class Object at runtime and perform introspection.

MetaData is data about data.A very important technique of specifying metadata is using annotations having Runtime RetentionPolicy.. see @Annotation.Reflection can come very handy to  extract the annotation values...Some examples of Annotations are @Entity annotation in Hibernate or @XML in JAX or @Transaction in Spring..Metadata along with Reflection is used in several places Like JUnit or Spring Framework.

Answer (score 3):

It's better explained at [Reflection (computer programming) - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)

> In computer science, `reflection` is the ability of a computer `program` to examine (see type introspection) and modify the structure and behavior (specifically the `values`, `meta-data`, `properties` and `functions`) of the program at `run-time`.

`reflection` is a technique to extract `meta-data` of the program at run-time.

---

#### What is Meta-data?

This is also explained at [Metadata - wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metadata)

> `Metadata` is "data about data".

The term is ambiguous, as it is used for two fundamentally different concepts (types).

- `Structural` metadata is about the design and specification of data structures and is more properly called *"data about the containers of data"*;
- `Descriptive` metadata, on the other hand, is about individual instances of application data, the data content.